# Getting segmentation fault in fread/fwrite loop, copying file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fwrite, fread, feof

I am to copy a file from the inputed source to the inputed destination. I am getting a segmentation fault error about 2 seconds after the destination is entered. The output file is created so `fopen()` is working.

I looked online and I see a lot of `c=getc(fp)`. I prefer `fread()` and `fwrite()` for this question because it's a little more basic.

### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//void rmnewline(char *string);
void remove_last_newline(char *str);

int main()
{
  char x[3];
  x[0]='y';
  int ch;

  while(x[0]=='y'||x[0]=='Y')
  {
    char source[256], destination[256];
    int *a;

    printf("Enter a source file: ");
    fgets(source, 256, stdin);
    if (source[254] == '\n' && source[255] == '\0') { while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n'); }
    remove_last_newline(source);

    printf("Enter a destination file: ");
    fgets(destination, 256, stdin);
    if (destination[254] == '\n' && destination[255] == '\0') { while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n'); }
    remove_last_newline(destination);

    FILE *sp, *dp;

    sp = fopen(source, "r");
    if (sp == NULL) { printf("ERROR: Could not open source file."); exit(1); }
    dp = fopen(destination, "w");
    if (dp == NULL) { printf("ERROR: Could not open destination file."); exit(1); }
    while(1)
    {
      fread(a, 1, 1, sp);
      if (feof(sp))
      break;
      fwrite(a, 1, 1, dp);
    }

    fclose(sp);
    fclose(dp);

    printf("Run Again?(y/n):");
    fgets(x, 2, stdin);
    while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n');
 }

}

/*void rmnewline(char *string)
{
    int i, l = strlen(string);

    for(i=0; i<=l; i++)
    {
      if(string[i] == '\0')
         return;
      if(string[i] == '\n')
     {
       string[i] == '\0';
       return;
     }
  }

}*/

void remove_last_newline(char *str) {
    if (*str == '\0') return; /* do nothing if the string is empty */
    while(str[1] != '\0') str++; /* search for the end of the string */
    if (*str == '\n') *str = '\0'; /* if the last character is newline, delete it */
}
```

Comment: You should check the return values of `fopen`.

Comment: fgets() reads a line *including* the \n . You should remove that first.

Comment: Conceptual error here: `if (source[254] == '\n' && source[255] == '\0')` (and again with the destination): it's not the last character in the *buffer* that may be a newline, but the last read character instead.

Comment: "The output file is created so fopen() is working" - but only for the write file.

Comment: If user  types `Y` then enter, `fgets(x, 2, stdin);` only saves `"Y"` with its null character leaving the `'\n'` in `stdin` for the next input function.

Comment: `fgets(source, 256, stdin); if (source[254] == '\n' && source[255] == '\0')`  --> may lead to undefined behavior.  Do not use `source` until check the return value from `fgets()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` store the newline character read in the buffer.

It may prevent `fopen` to open "the specified file" and `fopen` may return `NULL`.

Please delete newline characters if they are in the buffer.
This can be done using this function:

```
void remove_last_newline(char *str) {
    if (*str == '\0') return; /* do nothing if the string is empty */
    while(str[1] != '\0') str++; /* search for the end of the string */
    if (*str == '\n') *str = '\0'; /* if the last character is newline, delete it */
}
```

please pass `source` and `destination` to this function after reading file names to them.

Comment: I will look into this, but could you explain why fread will not read my new line byte. I don't understand. How would new lines be added if the text file is a new line?

EDIT: Nevermind, I understand

Comment: Candidate simplification `void remove_last_newline(char *str) { str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0'; }`

Comment: @Andrew Ricci `fread()` failed because `fopen()` failed.  It is not a issue of new lines in the file.  Robust code checks the results of all IO operations (`fgets, fopen, fread`, etc.)

Comment: @chux, I added the method after my own version of it failed. I still end up with seg fault.

Comment: @Andrew Ricci  Are all the return values from IO functions checked?  If not, save debug time and add tests to your code.

Comment: @chux, I printed the source and destination string, they looks fine. And I checked the return value of fread and fwrite, again fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91256/discussion-between-chux-and-andrew-ricci).

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of `fopen`.
The program is getting SEGFAULT at `fread(a, 1, 1, sp);`
This happens when SP is NULL. Since the program trying to read only one byte there will not be any chance of overflow.

`fopen` fails because the source consists of newline character at the end. If you remove `newline` character from the source and destination before calling fopen your program will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is leaving the `'\n'` in the filename and then the following `fopen()` failed, code did not check `fopen()` return value.  Other 2 answers well answered that and at least 1 deserves acceptance.

Subsequent OP edit changed `int a[1]` to `int *a` causing a new fault.  Suggest changing to

```
char a[1];
```